# Variable inside double quotes in PHP array keys

Tags: php, arrays, double, quotes, key

I've something weird into my code and I really don't get the behavior.
I always used array with string variables keys like this:

```
$string = "my key";  
$array[$string] = "my value";
```

But in one case, it doesn't work. I'm forced to put `$string` into double quotes, otherwise my array remains empty.
I really don't understand why. Moreover, further in my code I use the same `"$string"` as an id to create an another array, and it works fine without double quotes.

Here is my code where double quotes are needed (`array[]`):

```
foreach($xml2->menu as $children) {  
   $id = $children['id'];  
   $this->array["$id"] = $children->label;//Problem here
}
```

And here, the code without double quotes (`$resultArray[]`):

```
for($i=0; $i < count($idArray); $i++){  
   $id = $idArray[$i];  
   $resultArray[$id] = $this->array[$id];//Problem here
}
```

Does someone have any idea about why this is happening?

Edit:
The content of `$idArray[$i]` and `$children[$id]` is some string like `"about"`, `"contact"` etc.
And when I say "it doesn't work", I mean that the created array is `null`.

Comment: Can you write what $children['id'] and $idArraypp[$i] contain?. When you say "it doesn't work" do you get Error/Warning or is it just the variable is __null__?

Answer (score 0):

Does $children["id"] contain an object? Then type it to an int:

```
$id = (int) $children["id"];
```

Then you can use it again as $id.

Comment: $children["id"] is just a string from an xml file ("id" is the attribute name of the element)

Comment: Find out if it's an object (var_dump() it to see). If so, then type cast it to an int or string (whatever needed).